# SPI xfer2 callback possible?

Tags: python, spi, interrupts

I would like to control 10 different devices with SPI. As there is not enough ChipSelect outputs I use GPIO to toggle a MUX on the clock. Problem is I have to wait until the SPI is done transmitting before changing the GPIO to the next device.
Is there a way to set a callback function that will execute once spi.xfer2 is done 'transmitting'? Waiting or sleeping is an accurate and would result in a waste of time.

10 devices, each transmission is 960 bytes long (or 7680 bits). I would like to do 60 transmissions to all the devices each second which means a total of 576kB or ~4Mb (4MHz should do it but I set the frequency it to 8Mhz).
Python 3.5.3

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev, **At this time there is no async I/O support; everything is purely synchronous.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the spi.xfer2() call returns the SPI transfer has been completed.  So unless you are doing the transfers in multiple threads there is no problem.

E.g. the following will work.

```py
while True:
    select CS 1
    spi.xfer2()
    select CS 2   
    spi.xfer2()
    ...
    select CS 10
    spi.xfer2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Muxing SCL seems unusual!

Why not multiplex CS (if you want to use the inbuilt drivers).

There is no magic about CS - you can use ANY GPIO pins.
I believe [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/sitemap.html) has inbuilt support for this.

I would expect the return value from spiWrite to indicate success.

```
int spiWrite(unsigned handle, char *buf, unsigned count)
This function writes count bytes of data from buf to the SPI device associated with the handle. 

handle: >=0, as returned by a call to spiOpen
   buf: the data bytes to write
 count: the number of bytes to write


Returns the number of bytes transferred if OK, otherwise PI_BAD_HANDLE, PI_BAD_SPI_COUNT, or PI_SPI_XFER_FAILED.
```

Comment: The issue is not muxing CS or SCL but to know when to change the mux.